# Unable to get images on my web page while using ServletFilter

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I am unbale to get images on my jsp page while using ServletFilters on the url pattern. Please Help so  that I can get images on my web page.

Filter CODE:

```
package com.peckuk.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class AdminFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String test = filterConfig.getInitParameter("test-param");
        System.out.println("Init Method" + test);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        System.out.println("doFilter Method");
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String role = session.getAttribute("role").toString();
        if (role.equals("admin")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            out.println("Invalid user role");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy Method");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the URL pattern in filter mapping accordingly that it doesn't match image URLs.

E.g. `.jsp` files only:

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

or everything in `/pages` folder only:

```
<url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
```

or whatever covers all your restricted resources.

An alternative is to put all images (and CSS and JS files!) in a specific folder like `/resources` and have your filter to check if the current request URI doesn't point to that folder and if so, then just continue the request as if nothing happened.

```
if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + "/resources")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```